# UseState altera para undefined no momento de salvar a foto

Tags: react-native

Estou precisando salvar o caminho da foto tirada através do método camera.takePictureAsync. Criei a variável através do conceito do Hook conforme a definição abaixo:

```
const [path,setPath] = useState('');
```

Quando  o método setPath é utilizado e executo o  console.log('Caminho : ',path); aparece o valor undefined. Aparentemente a variável path não está sendo alterada. Não sei o que pode estar acontecendo.

segue a function que estou utilzando.

```
async function  takePicture(camera){
          const options = {quality:0.5,base64:true};
          const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
          console.log('URI: ',data.uri);
          setCapturedPhoto(data.uri);
          setOpen(true);
    
          let v = '"' + data.uri + '"';
    
          setPath(v)
          console.log('Caminho : ',path);
    
          //chama função salvar a foto
          await savePicture(data.uri); 
           
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Encontrei a resposta. Para quem precisar segue o link abaixo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505954/image-picker-save-uri-with-hook